# Using powershell to modify notes.ini

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that parses a lotus notes INI file and replaces text inside the file. But only the replaced text is showing up in the output file.

```
# Example of PowerShell -replace parameter
## Get-DistinguishedName -- look up a DN from a user's (login) name 
function Get-DistinguishedName { 
Param($UserName)
   $ads = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]'')
   $ads.filter = "(&(objectClass=Person)(samAccountName=$UserName))"
   $s = $ads.FindOne()
   return $s.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName
}

clear-Host
set-executionpolicy remotesigned

$original_file = '.\notes.ini'
$destination_file =  '.\notes2.ini'
$OS = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_OperatingSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName .
$username = [Environment]::UserName
$userprofile = $env:userprofile
$fullname =  Get-DistinguishedName($username) | %{$data = $_.split(","); $data[0].Substring(3)}
write-Host "Creating $userprofile"

if (($OS.Version -eq "5.1.2600") -or ($OS.Version -eq "5.2.3790")) {
   $lookupTable = @{
       '^SU_FILE_CLEANUP=' = 'SU_FILE_CLEANUP=' + $userprofile + '\Local Settongs\Application Data\smkits' 
       '%username%' = $username 
       '%fullname%' = $fullname 
       '%userprofile%' = $userprofile 
       '^Directory=' = 'Directory=' + $userprofile + '\Local Settongs\Application Data\Lotus\Notes\Data'}
} else {
   $lookupTable = @{
       'SU_FILE_CLEANUP=' = 'SU_FILE_CLEANUP=' + $userprofile + '\AppData\Roaming\smkits' 
       '%username%' = $username
       '%fullname%' = $fullname
       '%userprofile%' = $userprofile
       'Directory=' = 'Directory=' + $userprofile + '\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data'}
}

Get-Content -Path $original_file | ForEach-Object { 
    $line = $_
    $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($line -match $_.Key)
        {
            $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
            #break
        }
    }
    write-Host $line
} | Set-Content -Path $destination_file
```

What am I missing

Answer (score 1):

On this line, you are writing he output of the replace operator onto the pipeline, this will then get picked up by Set-Content

```
            $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
```

whereas on this line, you are writing the output to the host (i.e. the powershell console) it will not end up on the pipeline and will not get picked up up Set-Content:

```
    write-Host $line
```

To fix this, just replace write-host with write-output:

```
    Write-Output $line
```